# Is there a way to show on map only certain records in one layer that overlap with another layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial, arcgis, layer

I have a shapefile of all of the California Counties and another shapefile of the Central Valley (see pic). I want to only display counties if they overlap with the central valley - even if only a portion are in the Valley. So that would be 20 if the 58 records. I tried spatial join using 'contain' and 'intersect' but the join still showed all counties. I also tried just deleting the rows in the attribute table which was the only solution and that did work. But I seek a faster way and would prefer to not delete the records[image] in the attribute table instead of deleting.

Answer (score -1):

Spatial Join should do what you want. But to filter only the intersected counties you will need to uncheck "Keep All Target Feature" option.

The behaviour you've experienced should happen if you select "California Counties" as Target Features and "Central Valley" as Join Feature and also having "Keep All Target Features" option checked.

[image]